# Do these files need to be pushed to Github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made a Rails application.
Do i need to push these files to Github?

```
.browserslistrc
 
.gitattributes

.rspec
 
.ruby-version
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answers are "if you want", and "there's no reason not to".

All of these files do something to make it easier to replicate your code base and setup on another machine. None of them contain secrets that shouldn't be shared.

- [.browserslistrc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserslist)

  > The config to share target browsers and Node.js versions between different front-end tools.
- [.gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)

  > a simple text file that gives attributes to pathnames.

  > These attributes affect how the contents stored in the repository are copied to the working tree files when commands such as git switch, git checkout and git merge run. They also affect how Git stores the contents you prepare in the working tree in the repository upon git add and git commit.
- [.rspec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/configuration/read-command-line-configuration-options-from-files)

  > Read command line configuration options from files
- [.ruby-version](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-manage-your-ruby-versions/)

  > Many Ruby (or Rails) projects will include a simple .ruby-version file, which simply specifies a version number

Comment: `.rspec` generally should just contain user preferences but if you (miss)use the `--require` option the entire test suite can fail to run. `.ruby-version` in itself does nothing - its only with Ruby version managers and shell hooks that it will cause you to change into the correct Ruby version when you enter the directory.

Comment: Agreed, @max. I just grabbed what I thought were succinct descriptions from the sources. And I debated going into version managers, but figured it was too verbose for the question.